# Join and OrderBy within with laravel eloquent query

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, join, eloquent

I want to display ordered list of stores based on cities from a brand.

This is the code I tried

```
 $brand = Brand::where('slug','=',$slugurl)
      ->with(['stores' => function($q){
        $q->where('status', 1)
        ->join('cities', function ($join){
              $join->on('cities.id', '=', 'stores.city_id')->orderBy('cities.sort_number', 'DESC');
        });

      }])
      ->firstOrFail();
```

The relationship of the tables :

> Brand hasMany Stores and Stores belongTo Cities

The listings results output is not ordered based on cities sort_number. Any idea how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is useless to `order` in `join`'s closure.

You need to append the `orderBy` after `join`:

```php
$brand = Brand::where('slug','=',$slugurl)
      ->with(['stores' => function($q){
        $q->where('status', 1)
          ->join('cities', 'cities.id', '=', 'stores.city_id')
          ->orderBy('cities.sort_number', 'DESC');
      }])
      ->firstOrFail();
```

This query convert to raw sql is:

```sql
select * from brands where slug = ? limit 1;

select * from stores 
join cities on cities.id = stores.city_id 
where status = 1 and stores.brand_id in (?)
order by cities.sort_number desc;
```

Comment: the result order is still same, no ordered list of stores

Comment: @TomKur I have tried it, it works, can u post the results that is not sorted

Comment: It works when I put the join and ordered in my model

Comment: @TomKur I think you can use `DB::getQueryLog()`. it will help u output the raw sql, and you will find the `order by` is there or not